# Months between 2 dates in netezza sql

Tags: sql, datetime, netezza

In Netezza,we have a months_between function that gives months between 2 dates:
I suspect, it first calculates days between dates and then divides by 30?

Is there a way to write sql in netezza so that I get integer values like this:
If the 2 dates are in same month, return 0.
Else return the # of months. i.e 31Aug15 and 01SEP15 should return 1 since they are in different months.

If I cast the o/p of months_between to an integer, unfortunately, I am at the mercy of ROUNDING.

So `cast (months_between(31Aug15 , 01SEP15) as integer)` will return 0, not 1.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Netezza is new to me ! Can you post your work here, may be I can help in correcting it  .

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use the last day of the month:

```
cast (months_between(last_day(31Aug15) , last_day(01SEP15)) as integer)
```

which translates to:

```
cast (months_between(31Aug15 , 31SEP15) as integer)
```

And that gives a result of 1

Comment: I've been here month than once, so I wish I could give this more than one upvote